# Simulink: Component doesn't show in the Diagnostics Viewer Tab (Size computation error)

Tags: matlab, buffer, simulink

I'm trying to troubleshoot an error on Simulink but the Diagnostic Viewer window is being extremely vague and it's not showing a specific model for the error. Anyone know what this error might be?:
`Size computation for 'buffer' evaluated to -1. To specify an inherited size use the literal '-1'.`

Screenshot:

[image]

It's part of a big project but I'm not sure where to even look since it's not linking to any component model. I'd never encountered this error before.

Any help would be appreciated